# How do I dynamically change the row height of a UIpickerview throughout its lifetime?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Just to clarify, I am not asking how to set the row height once in the beginning when the UIpickerview is being set up. I know you use pickerView:rowHeightForComponent for that purpose.

However, what I am asking is if I want pickerView:rowHeightForComponent to return a variable value, where the value can change during the lifetime of the UIpickerview, e.g., in response to the click of a button or change in a default setting.

I found that, unfortunately, pickerView:rowHeightForComponent is only called once, in the beginning, when iOS is setting up the UIpickerview. After that, it never calls pickerView:rowHeightForComponent again, so can't pick up the change in the value that pickerView:rowHeightForComponent would return if only it were called again.

I suppose I could just release the UIpickerview and set up another one, forcing iOS to call pickerView:rowHeightForComponent again, but this might be inconvenient, and might need saving of state information. Is there another, easier way, to dynamically change the row height? Thanks!

Searching around, I found [Changing UIPickerView row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397947/changing-uipickerview-row-height) (which is only for the first time setup of the row height) and [How to change the size of row in UIPickerView by button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331188/how-to-change-the-size-of-row-in-uipickerview-by-button-click) , which talks about the rowSizeForComponent method, which appears to just use a cached value for the row height.

Here's the portion of code that attempts to change the row height, together with testing reloadAllComponents: as suggested by @RileyE

```
NSLog(@"before, scrollviewSpacing is %d", self.mainViewController.IACscrollviewSpacing);
if (0.0 != fromDefaultsScrollviewSpacing) {
    self.mainViewController.IACscrollviewSpacing = (UInt8) round (60.0 - fromDefaultsScrollviewSpacing);
}
NSLog(@"now scrollviewSpacing is %d", self.mainViewController.IACscrollviewSpacing);
NSLog(@"rowsizeforcomponent height is %f", [self.mainViewController.PickIPAddress rowSizeForComponent:1].height);
[self.mainViewController.PickIPAddress reloadAllComponents];
NSLog(@"rowsizeforcomponent height is %f", [self.mainViewController.PickIPAddress rowSizeForComponent:1].height);
[self.mainViewController.PickIPAddress reloadComponent:1];
NSLog(@"rowsizeforcomponent height is %f", [self.mainViewController.PickIPAddress rowSizeForComponent:1].height);
```

which gives the following output on the console:

> 2012-11-29 02:32:14.681 IP Address Calculator[6404:c07] before, scrollviewSpacing is 39 
>   2012-11-29 02:32:18.913 IP Address Calculator[6404:c07] now scrollviewSpacing is 22 
>   2012-11-29 02:32:20.196 IP Address Calculator[6404:c07] rowsizeforcomponent height is 39.000000
>   2012-11-29 02:32:28.865 IP Address Calculator[6404:c07] rowsizeforcomponent height is 39.000000
>   2012-11-29 02:32:30.903 IP Address Calculator[6404:c07] rowsizeforcomponent height is 39.000000

and in MainViewController (which is the UIpickerviewdelegate), I have

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return self.IACscrollviewSpacing; }
```

Furthermore, I set a breakpoint here, and I see it only gets called when the UIPickerview is initially being set up, and never again.

Comment: Are you saying that `rowHeightForComponent:` is called again if you call `reloadComponent:` on the picker view?

Comment: I'm saying that reloadAllComponents: doesn't call rowHeightForComponent: again, which is a problem for me. If it does, then it would pick up the new value I want to use for the row height.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. I meant "isn't called", not "is called". You've confirmed that now. This is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

All delegate methods are called again and updated when you call `[yourPicker reloadAllComponents];`

Check out the [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) and [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDataSource) docs. Check out the "Reloading the View Picker" section, especially.

Comment: Read the question again. It's not about table views.

Comment: Thanks, but it is a UIpickerview, not a UItableview. There is no reloadData method. There is reloadAllComponents or reloadComponent: but these only read the data again (UIpickerviewdatasource protocol methods), and don't call the UIpickerviewDelegate protocols methods (at least, not pickerView:rowHeightForComponent).

Comment: @rmaddy Ah. My bad, however, its the same thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I know that this works for me. If it doesn't work for you to change the row height, then something is wrong in what you're calling.

Comment: @RileyE I just did my own test and when I call either `reloadAllComponents` or `reloadComponent:` on a picker view, all of the appropriate delegate/data source methods are called except for the `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` method. I tested under iOS 6. Are you sure that the `rowHeightForComponent:` is called for you after the picker is fully displayed and later reloaded?

Comment: @RileyE It changes the row height for you? Will update the question with code, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy I had a picker in a previous project with dynamic content and when the content changed, calling reloadAllComponents would redefine the row height. I built it on iOS 4.3, though. Maybe it doesn't work  now?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `UIPickerView` can dynamically change the row height.

But I did implement a picker view name [`DLPickerView`](https://github.com/danleechina/DLPickerView). You can return different height for different row. Theoretically it can also change the row height throughout its lifetime